# Ptx assembly aborted due to errors

Tags: c++, cuda, ptx

I have tried to write programm for multiply CSR matrix and vector on C/CUDA 5.5 in MS Visual Studio 2012, but faced with ptx error.
Listing of my code:

```
__global__ void multKernelSymm(double* s, double* u, double* val, int* rowPtr, int* colInd)
    {
        int l = 0, jl, i;
        int idx = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;

        l = rowPtr[idx] - 1;
        for ( i = 0; i < (rowPtr[idx + 1] - rowPtr[idx]); i++){
            jl = colInd[l] - 1;
            s[idx] = s[idx] + val[l] * u[jl];
            l+=1;
        }

        l = 0;
        l = rowPtr[idx] - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < (rowPtr[idx + 1] - rowPtr[idx]); i++){
            jl = colInd[l] - 1;
            if(jl > idx)
                atomicAdd(&s[jl], val[l] * u[idx]);
                //s[jl] = s[jl] + val[l] * u[idx];
            l+=1;
        }


    }

    __device__ double atomicAdd(double* address, double val)
    {
         unsigned long long int* address_as_ull =
         (unsigned long long int*)address;
         unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
         do {
            assumed = old;
            old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed, __double_as_longlong(val + __longlong_as_double(assumed)));
         } while (assumed != old);
         return __longlong_as_double(old);
    }
```

This I get in VS:

```
 C:\Users\Дмитрий\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\matrix mult simple\matrix mult simple>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o x64\Debug\kernel.cu.obj "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\matrix mult simple\matrix mult simple\kernel.cu" 
1>  ptxas C:/Users/AACE~1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_00001b88_00000000-4_kernel.ptx, line 479; : fatal error : Parsing error near '-': syntax error
1>ptxas : fatal error : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
1>  kernel.cu
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.0.targets(597,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o x64\Debug\kernel.cu.obj "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\matrix mult simple\matrix mult simple\kernel.cu"" exited with code -1.
1>
 >     ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Ho I can fix it?

Comment: Does this even compile ? What do you expect `double atomicAdd(s[jl], val[l] * u[idx]);` to do ?

Comment: as `double atomicAdd();` i used example from CUDA programming guide. But atomicCAS and `__longlong_as_double` and `__double_as_longlong` undefined. Also i wrote variant of programm with float instead of double (cause `float atomicAdd();` natively exists in CUDA) but it undefined too.

Comment: You're missing the point - the syntax is not even valid.

Comment: @PaulR, may be, but i made a copy of double AtomicAdd function from Programming guide and functions (I wrote them above) undefined. May be I need to use more headers, than just `cuda_runtime.h`?

Comment: You're *still* missing the point - the keyword `double` should not be present - it looks like you've just copied and pasted the function *definition* without really understanding what you're doing. Hint: where do you expect the result of `atomicAdd()` to be stored ?

Comment: @PaulR, sorry, fixed it. But atomicCAS and double_as_longlong undefined - and its my main problem

Comment: I modified mu question and added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your code to compile by making 3 changes:

1. As @PaulR indicated, remove the `double` keyword when calling your custom `atomicAdd` function.
2. The first parameter of `atomicAdd` should be a *pointer* to the address you want to update (the address you want to add the value to.)  Instead you are passing the value at that address.  So your function call should look like this:

   ```
   atomicAdd(&(s[jl]), val[l] * u[idx]);
   ```
3. Finally, move the declaration and definition of your custom `atomicAdd` function to *before* your kernel definition.

With those changes I could get your code to compile.

Comment: Thanks you, I fixed it. But I still get `atomicCAS` and `__longlong_as_double` undefined.

Comment: My best guess is that you have an incorrectly configured project in visual studio.  Either you are compiling a .cpp file instead of a .cu file, or you have not found the proper place to add the `-arch=sm_20` switch.  As a test, you could start with one of the cuda samples projects that are provided, make sure you can compile one of those, then add your code to that project.  In addition to adding the `-arch=sm_20` switch, you should remove any other switches (`sm_10`) etc. because they will cause an error.

Comment: Samples works perfectly. I tried to specify `sm_20, compute_20` in CUDA properties of the project but it din`t work. Also, I read before that `-arch=sm_20` is equal to adding `sm_20`, `compute_20` instead of `sm_10, compute_10`. And I really compile .cu file.

Comment: I added vs command. This command i get when change default to sm_20. If I use default setings - I just get some functions as undefined.

Comment: This is a different kind of error than what you were describing.  I don't see anything about `atomicCAS` and `__longlong_as_double` undefined.  You'll need to reconfigure VS to show all the output from commands issued, so we can see the exact issue being reported by ptxas.  There are VS settings to control what level of output is shown in the console window.